# Angular 9 data from api call isn't populating dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, interpolation

Having some problems with filling my drop down menu with data from my API. I need help figuring out what I am doing wrong because I am getting no errors in the console.

Service.ts method call:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderExceptionReportService extends ApiServiceBase {

  private apiRoute: string = 'exception-report';
  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService) {
    super(http, configService);

  }

  public async GetExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<ExceptionReportSessionData[]> {
    if (!this.appSettings) {
      this.appSettings = await this.configService.loadConfig().toPromise();
    }

    return await this.http.get<ExceptionReportSessionData[]>(this.appSettings.apiSetting.apiAddress + this.apiRoute + '/session-data')
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
      .toPromise()

  }

  }
```

component.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-exception-report',
  templateUrl: './order-exception-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-exception-report.component.scss']
})
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {

  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[];
  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {
  }

  getExceptionReportSessionData() {
    this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionData = data;
        });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


}
```

html where I need the data:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option value="" *ngFor="let session of sessionData">{{session.SessionName}}</option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

Interface.ts file:

```
export interface ExceptionReportSessionData {
  SessionName: string,
  ReportFiles: Array<string>
}
```

Comment: What does `this.configService.loadConfig()` return? I don't think `this.appSettings.apiSetting.apiAddress + this.apiRoute` assigns the correct URL. Do you see the correct response in the network tab of the browser?

Comment: @MichaelD it returns: this.http.get<AppSettings>(OIDC_CONFIG_URL). It's basically setting up the first part of the api url. It is hitting the endpoint.

Comment: You need to then retrieve the value from `this.configService.loadConfig()` first. You could do everything using RxJS methods and operators. I've posted an answer. It is better to handle the observables directly without converting to promises since Angular HttpClient also uses it. The sooner you get used it the better.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it appears the `this.configService.loadConfig()` returns an HTTP observable as well.

In that case, you could avoid using promises and streamline the process using RxJS method [`iff`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) to check if the `this.appSettings` variable is defined and [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to switch to the target request once `appSettings` is retrieved.

Try the following

```js
public GetExceptionReportSessionData(): Observable<ExceptionReportSessionData[]> {
  return iff(() => 
      this.appSettings, 
      of(this.appSettings), 
      this.configService.loadConfig().pipe(tap(appSettings => this.appSettings = appSettings))).pipe(
    switchMap(appSettings => this.http.get<ExceptionReportSessionData[]>(appSettings.apiSetting.apiAddress + this.apiRoute + '/session-data')),
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

[`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator is used to tap into the result and store it into `this.appSettings` variable. [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) method is used to send an observable of `this.appSettings` since `switchMap` operator expects an observable.

You could then subscribe to the function in the component

```js
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {
  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[];
  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {}

  getExceptionReportSessionData() {
    this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData().subscribe(
      data => { this.sessionData = data; },
      error => { }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getExceptionReportSessionData();
  }
}
```

Comment: In the service on the GetExceptionReportSessionData method I am getting the error: this.appSettings is no assignable to type 'boolean'